# Reset text field on UIButton press

Tags: ios, swift

I have buttons and have them linked to the interface, as well as text fields. I'm trying to accomplish 2 things today.

Create a button Toggle & Tally up and change the text in the boxes. So if a reset button is pressed it will change the text to all "0".

Here's where I'm having issues.

```
    btnReride.state = 0
    txtJudgeScore1.value(forKey: "0")
```

The state will not change and the score will not change. I did put a breakpoint and message box in to make sure the routine is running, but nothing happens, and no alert is popping up. Any ideas?

Comment: This line `txtJudgeScore1.value(forKey: "0")` does nothing.

Comment: what would the proper coding be? Since I've posted I've still been researching and just keep getting frustrated. many of the tutorials are only designed for IOS.

Comment: It is not even clear to me what you are _trying_ to do. You've only shown two lines, with no context — we don't even know what method they are in, or how that method is called.

Comment: `class View1Controller: NSViewController {    @IBAction func btnNoScore(_ sender: Any) {
        // Set Score to zero
            txtJudgeScore1.value(forKey: "0")
            txtJudgeScore2.value(forKey: "0")
            txtJudgeScore3.value(forKey: "0")
        
        
        lblScore.value(forKey: "Score: \(score)")        // Reset Judges Scores Function
    } }`

Comment: Okay First part of the question is answered. I found an article.
When Using NSTextField it uses `txtJudgeScore1.stringValue = "My Value Here"`

Still trying to figure out how to leave a button highlighted or in the "ON" Position like a toggle.

Comment: There is no such thing as NSTextField in iOS. But your question is tagged as iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the textfields on a button click you will do something like tis:

```
@IBAction func btnReride(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        btnReride.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, Figured it out now.

Use these to set the Button State. Make sure you have it set to either a On-Off or Toggle in the storyboard properties page.

```
 `   btnPenalty.state = NSOffState
    //btnPenalty.setNextState()
    btnReride.state = NSOffState`
```